# I want to animate UITableView on Button Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have `UITableView` and i want to animate when user click on Button.

**For Selected State    --> BOTTOM TO TOP**

**For UnSelected State  --> TOP TO BOTTOM**

For that I have tried Below Code.
**My TableView frame (0,39, width, height)**

```
- (IBAction)onInviteFriendsButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected =! sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected) {
        CGRect napkinBottomFrame = self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame;
        napkinBottomFrame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame = napkinBottomFrame;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^{
            self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame = CGRectMake(0, 39, self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame.size.width, self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame.size.height);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){/*done*/}];
    }
    else {
        CGRect napkinBottomFrame = self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame;
        napkinBottomFrame.origin.y = 39;
        self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame = napkinBottomFrame;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown animations:^{
            self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame = CGRectMake(0, -[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame.size.width, self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame.size.height);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){/*done*/}];
    }
}
```

When i click button it will animate from **BOTTOM TO TOP** properly.
but when i click button again it will again gone from **BOTTOM TO TOP**.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set `frame.origin.y` of tableview is -y or XY coordinate.

```
    self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame = CGRectMake(0, -[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame.size.width, self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame.size.height);
```

replace with this

```
    self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame.size.width, self.tblVWInviteFriend.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (IBAction)onInviteFriendsButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected =! sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected) {
        CGRect napkinBottomFrame = txtAOP.frame;
        napkinBottomFrame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        txtAOP.frame = napkinBottomFrame;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^{
            txtAOP.frame = CGRectMake(0, 39, txtAOP.frame.size.width, txtAOP.frame.size.height);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){/*done*/}];
    }
    else {
        CGRect napkinBottomFrame = txtAOP.frame;
        napkinBottomFrame.origin.y = -[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        txtAOP.frame = napkinBottomFrame;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown animations:^{
            txtAOP.frame = CGRectMake(0,39 , txtAOP.frame.size.width, txtAOP.frame.size.height);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){/*done*/}];
    }
}
```